# New contributor is not shown in public repository

Tags: git, github

I just invited a user to collaborate with my public repository, and she accepted my invitation. But her name is not shown in repository title and repository still show 1 contributor. In manage section, I can see her name as one of the contributors.

what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of contributors to a repository as listed on the repository's front page is the number of people who have code in that repository (or possibly the main branch).  It doesn't reflect how many people have permissions on the repository.

For example, when looking at https://github.com/git/git, there are 1366 contributors, but far, far fewer have permissions to access the repository.

Once the user has code in the project, the contributor count will increase accordingly.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Because she doesn't contribute yet. Thanks a lot.